# How to run Java from Python

Tags: python-3.x

So basically I'm going to receive a string of Java code from a website and need to run the java code and check the result to see if it is correct in Python.

It also needs to be secure (ie can't have access to the os, can't take too long to execute and needs a memory limit) if this is possible.

Thanks!